# Stored Procedure varchar value more than it should be

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The `varchar` value of my stored procedure can contain 200 characters. When there are more than 200 characters, I want a `raiserror` and a `rollback` of the transaction.
How to do this? I use SQL Server

I'm having this:

```
@employeeid int,
@questionid int,
@date date,
@comment varchar(200),
@score int

)
as

begin

begin transaction

update contentment
set date = @date, comment= @comment, score = @score
where employeeid= @employeeid and questionid= @quesitonid


if @comment> @comment
begin 

    rollback
    raiserror ('error more than 200 characters', 16, 1)
    return
end

commit
end
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: The first thing your stored procedure sees is already `@comment varchar(200)`. It's not going to exceed 200 characters. The truncation will happen before your procedure is called, and it will not be aware of that.

Comment: But if the user inserts more than 200 characters? What will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do anything special. As *@GSerg* commented, the parameter type is `varchar(200)` which means that the procedure will **never** get more than 200 characters, so there is nothing you can do within the procedure itself, so you're better off just removing the validation from it.

You can attempt some validation **before** calling the procedure itself. It's better to do either client-side or in another procedure that wraps this.

Another option is to change the definition to take a `varchar(max)` and validate the lenght there (as it'll now allow pretty much unlimited strings).